# Error running import-spweb on SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server

When trying to restore a site, to a site on the same Site Collection (even when trying to restore to the original site) using the following we are getting an error. We've narrowed the error down to when a Promoted Links list [FILE] restore is occurring. The content type of the list has been edited. We have successfully restored a default Promoted Links List.

Exporting with-
`powershell export-spweb "site" -path "export.cmp" -IncludeUserSecurity -Force`

Importing with -
`powershell import-spweb -identity "site" -path "export.cmp"`

Error message -
*import-spweb : The element 'WebPart' in namespace 'urn:deployment-manifest-schema' has invalid child element 
'ParameterBinding' in namespace 'urn:deployment-manifest-schema'. List of possible elements expected: 'Script, PagedRowset, 
PagedClientCallbackRowset, PagedRecurrenceRowset, ViewFields, ViewData, Query, RowLimit, RowLimitExceeded, Toolbar,*

Manifest.xml -

```xml
<SPObject Id="3edbb159-cc44-4b52-ae27-67f7daa285a6" ObjectType="SPFile" ParentId="b16899ff-5ae6-4eb8-ad45-97347338b74d" ParentWebId="cd853129-8ebc-4a4b-ac94-e05b3f0b251d" ParentWebUrl="/site" Url="/site/Lists/Buttons/AllItems.aspx">
        <File Url="Lists/Buttons/AllItems.aspx" Id="3edbb159-cc44-4b52-ae27-67f7daa285a6" ParentWebId="cd853129-8ebc-4a4b-ac94-e05b3f0b251d" ParentWebUrl="/calderdale" Name="AllItems.aspx" ListId="c4f8eed2-d9f3-492b-86ec-4a87e0fffa81" ParentId="b16899ff-5ae6-4eb8-ad45-97347338b74d" TimeCreated="2018-12-05T09:55:39" TimeLastModified="2018-12-05T09:55:39" Version="1.0" IsGhosted="true" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" SetupPathVersion="15" FileValue="0000000F.dat">
            <WebParts>
                <WebPart Name="b8f9de22-80f2-412e-a3f3-b82b562c2ac9" DisplayName="All Buttons" Flags="5" Hidden="false" Threaded="false" ReadOnly="false" RecurrenceRowset="false" FPModified="false" ModerationType="" Personal="false" OrderedView="false" ListId="c4f8eed2-d9f3-492b-86ec-4a87e0fffa81" ListRootFolderUrl="/calderdale/Lists/Buttons" Version="1" BaseViewID="3" Level="major" WebPartZoneID="Main" WebPartTypeId="a6524906-3fd2-ee4e-23ee-252d3c6e0dc9" IsIncluded="true" WebPartOrder="1" Type="0" FrameState="0"><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="Edit"/><FieldRef Name="TileOrder"/><FieldRef Name="Title"/><FieldRef Name="Description"/><FieldRef Name="LinkLocation"/><FieldRef Name="LaunchBehavior"/></ViewFields><ViewData/><Query><GroupBy Collapse="FALSE" GroupLimit="30"><FieldRef Name="ShowOn"/></GroupBy><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="TileOrder"/><FieldRef Name="Title"/></OrderBy></Query><Aggregations Value="Off"/><RowLimit Paged="TRUE">100</RowLimit><Mobile MobileItemLimit="3" MobileSimpleViewField="Title"/><XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink><JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink><ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)"/><ParameterBindings><ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)"/><ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)"/></ParameterBindings></WebPart>
            </WebParts>
        </File>
</SPObject>
```

Comment: are you exporting and importing in the same SharePoint Farm, or exporting from one environment and importing into another?  If they are two different farms, are the both at the same patch/cu level?

Comment: Sorry, yes. Same SharePoint farm. edited question to reflect.

Comment: Check that your destination site collection has all the same site collection level features activated as your source.

Comment: I've edited the question, happens when trying to restore over the top of the existing site, so with all the same site features enabled.